# Excel: Remove everything after ? in a url

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I already searched for formulas or add ins online but can't seem to find any formula for this.

I was wondering if I can remove everything after a question mark in a URL?

> http://www.site.com/index.php?98943j%klr

to

> http://www.site.com/index.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?",""))=LEN(A1),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1)-1))
```

to

- Cater for the `?` not appearing in A1 without raising an error
- Properly truncating the string to `http://www.site.com/index.php` .... your accepted answer doesnt adjust for the position of `?` and it will return `http://www.site.com/index.php?`

Comment: Hi Brett! Thank you for this! Was quite busy with work I forgot to thank you! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1))
```

Here A1 is your url

Comment: Doesn't produce the result requested.

Comment: @brettdj:- So you mean that LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1,1)-1) will give the expected result?

Comment: Did you test your answer? Yes, `LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1,1)-1)` or the shorter `LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1)-1)` will.

Comment: It actually worked for me. Though it shows ?, the new formula doesn't. Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: @user3075601:- I changed it back to the previous one as you say that it is working for you!

Comment: @user3075601 You asked to return `http://www.site.com/index.php`, the formula above returns `http://www.site.com/index.php?`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return another hyperlink, but only cosisting of everything before the question mark, you could use the following formula, having you URL in cell `A1`.

```
=HYPERLINK(LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1,1)-1))
```

Comment: This works great. But I don't need the hyperlink. But thank you! :)

Comment: +1 for the working part of `LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1,1)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

For a manual way, use find and replace:
find: ~?*
replace with: (nothing)

A comment above has the best answer: `LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1)-1)` 
with the -1 included.